# HTML Line Spacing in Numbered List, rendered in BIRT

Tags: html, html-lists, birt

I have a PDF rendering solution built on top of BIRT.
As part of the data poassed to the renderer, rich HTML text can be supplied.
HTML is supplied in this format:

```
<ul><li style="text-align:left;"><span style="font-size:12px;">
 <font face="Arial" color="#262626">Desc Num 1</font></span></li>
 <li style="text-align:left;"><span style="font-size:12px;">
 <font face="Arial" color="#262626">Desc Num 2</font></span></li>
 <li style="text-align:left;"><span style="font-size:12px;">
 <font face="Arial" color="#262626">Desc Num 3</font></span></li>
 <li style="text-align:left;"><span style="font-size:12px;">
 <font face="Arial" color="#262626">Desc Num 4</font></span></li>
 <li style="text-align:left;"><span style="font-size:12px;">
 <font face="Arial" color="#262626">Desc Num 5</font></span></li>
 <li style="text-align:left;"><span style="font-size:12px;">
 <font face="Arial" color="#262626">Desc Num 6</font></span></li></ul>
```

On certain systems (Production!) the list is rendered with huge spaces
between the items, but on other systems, the list appears correctly.

**Note**: It is only the Numbered list that I see this rendering issue

Image here of 2 rendering outputs, erroneous on left, correct on right
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfXau.png

Any suggestions what direction I could take to resolve this appreciated.
Ro

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML code posted, or in the CSS code embedded in it, there is nothing that causes the problem described. In fact, the screenshot indicates that the `font` markup has been ignored at least as regards to font face (the font surely isn’t Arial there).

You refer to “numbered list” twice, but the markup is `ul`, for “unnumbered” list (or, in reality, a bulleted list). The numbers in the screenshot thus come from somewhere else. It is possible, and easy, to turn a bulleted list into a numbered list in CSS. And presumably it’s some CSS settings (or some other formatting instructions outside the code posted) that add the extraneous spacing; it could be line height, or margin, or padding.

Comment: Right you are ... I had ordered and unordered lists in the test data, pasted HTML from one that did not match the screenshot. (Updated Code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a report I'm sure one of these sites will help you see where you are going wrong:

this class extracts styling from a report

http://tinyreport.googlecode.com/svn-history/r19/trunk/tinyreport-birt/src/main/java/com/bradrydzewski/tinyreport/birt/xpath/StyleFactory.java

Also here is the specification for BIRT

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/release20specs/BPS11_BIRTStyle_CSS_SPEC.pdf  You need to hack into their code and customize it to do what you want it to

Since you are using 3+ it has

- Ability to import CSS into a report design.
- Ability to import CSS into a library.

and here is a forum post similar to your question: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/365412/

and a blog which should help you:

http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2007/07/its-been-while-but-after-some-family.html